# Can I have a primary key/unique constraint on multiple properties that are unique in any order?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have the following model that's essentially a many-to-many relationship table.

```
public class Friend
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("UserA")]
    public int UserAId { get; set; }
    public virtual User UserA { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("UserB")]
    public int UserBId { get; set; }
    public virtual User UserB { get; set; }

    public DateTime Since { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Friendships are always two-way in my application. How can I constrain my backend from inserting both `new Friend { UserAId = 1, UserBId = 2 }` and `new Friend { UserAId = 2, UserBId = 1 }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the only one solution: to create manually constraint on your table (you can add migration and then write something like this):

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql(@"ALTER TABLE dbo.Friends ADD 
    CONSTRAINT CustomOrder CHECK (UserAId > UserBId)");
}

public override void Down()
{
    Sql(@"ALTER TABLE dbo.Friends DROP CONSTRAINT CustomOrder");
}
```

And now you can add only user's id pairs like that: 2 - 1, 5 - 3, but not 1 - 2 and 3 -5, so we have not duplicates as you wanted, but also you must provide assigning to UserA id value that will be more then UserB id value, but I think that it is not difficult for you.

Comment: "_but also you must provide assigning to UserA id value that will be more then UserB id value, but I think that it is not difficult for you._"  what does it mean? Should he check which id is bigger than the other ?  If so, checking id is also avoiding duplicate and there is no need to implement your code, isn't it ?

Comment: Not, bad comment. But my solution include concurrency issues resolving. For example, let's consider your suggestion: we have table with pairs: 1-2 and 5-4, then we check - can we insert 6-3 pair, of course we can, but parallel task perform insert(3-6) between our checking and inserting, table become (1-2, 5-4, 3-6) than we perform insert and result is (1-2, 5-4, 3-6, 6-3) - not cool. Let's consider my solution: table will be looks that way: (2-1,5-4) (2-1, because of ordering), after hidden insert table will be (2-1,5-4,6-3) and when we attempt to insert 6-3 again, we will have error.

Comment: Also we don't need to retrieve existing ids from database before each insert operation.

Comment: I ended up doing this, but using `<`. For some reason it seems more natural to me to have pairs like 1-3, 2-5, 3-4 instead of 3-1, 5-2, 4-3.

Comment: Small question, why the `@` in front of the strings?

Comment: @ indeed is needed only in Up() method, without it I should write this way: `Sql("ALTER TABLE dbo.Friends ADD\n"+ 
    "CONSTRAINT CustomOrder CHECK (UserAId > UserBId)");` it is not comfortable. And returning to @Engineert comment. You can forget to sort users before inserting or your db may will be used by others apps, that don't know about your politic(no duplicates), but this constraint guarantee that in table will not be duplicates and this fact not depends on anything.,